# limit of $\log(x)^{(k+1)}/x$

Tags: limits

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{\log^{k+1}(x)}{x}\right) = \lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{\frac{(k+1)\log^{k}(x)}{x}}{1}\right) = \lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{(k+1)(k)\log^{k-1}(x)}{x}\right) = \lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{(k+1)!}{x}\right) \Rightarrow 0$$

I used L'Hospital to get to $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{(k+1)(k)\log^{k-1}(x)}{x}\right)$$

But from there I don't understand how to get $$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{(k+1)!}{x}\right) $$

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you use l'Hopital's rule $k+1$ times?

Answer (score 1):

Set $k+1=m$ and substitute $x=e^{mt}$, so your limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{m^mt^m}{e^{mt}}=
\lim_{t\to\infty}m^m\left(\frac{t}{e^t}\right)^{\!m}
$$
Now apply l'Hôpital once.

Possibly, you want to prove the following result by induction:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\log x)^k}{x}=0
$$
For $k=0$ the result is obvious. Suppose it holds for $k$; then, applying l'Hôpital,
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\log x)^{k+1}}{x}=
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(k+1)(\log x)^k}{x}
$$
which is zero by the induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

simply by iteration of l'Hôpital, you actually did everything alright!
$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{(k+1)(k)\log^{k-1}(x)}{x}\right)=\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{(k+1)(k)\dots(2)\log^{1}(x)}{x}\right)=\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{(k+1)!}{x}\right)$ with $k!=1*2*\dots*k$ denoting the factorial.

bests

EDIT: I assumed $k \in \mathbb{N}$